# Laravel 5.3 Schema::create ENUM field is VARCHAR

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-schema-builder

I just created fresh migration. After running it I see my field `type` **not ENUM type**. It has a **VARCHAR(255) type instead**

```
Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->text('response');
  $table->enum('type', ['apple', 'paypal']);
  $table->smallInteger('flags');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Can somebody tell me what can be the reason. Am I missing something, I tried multiple times - getting same result.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.4 and Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Laravel [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/PostgresGrammar.php#L438)

```
protected function typeEnum(Fluent $column)
{
    $allowed = array_map(function ($a) {
        return "'{$a}'";
    }, $column->allowed);
    return "varchar(255) check (\"{$column->name}\" in (".implode(', ', $allowed).'))';
}
```

It will create a `varchar(255)` column and will add a constraint so that it allows only the specified strings.

Comment: How to modify with DB::statement() ?