# How can I create laravel migration with enum type column?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, migration

I am trying to create enum column in laravel migration. Upon executing the query it does create column in the table but checking in postgresql for created enum types, it shows theres none. Does anyone ever experience this?

I am using laravel 5.4, php 7 and vagrant

Migration code

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('restaurant_tables', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('_id');
            $table->string('tableNo', 100);
            $table->json('spatialLocation');
            $table->enum('tableStatus' , array('Occupied', 'Reserved', 'Vacant', 'For Cleaning'))->default('Vacant');
            $table->integer('numberOfCustomers');
            $table->integer('seatLimit');
            $table->string('tableDimension', 100);
            $table->enum('tableType', ['4x4','16x4','8x4']);
            $table->bigInteger('chairID');
        });

        Schema::table('restaurant_tables', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('chairID')->references('_id')->on('restaurant_chairs');
        });
    }
```

[image: Image in checking if enum data type created, and check if all tables are created]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.3 Schema::create ENUM field is VARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384827/laravel-5-3-schemacreate-enum-field-is-varchar)

Comment: @miken32 how can I implement it? the answer is pretty straightforward, would you like to explain a little bit more about it? the link you provide is related to my problem but the OP does not explain how he arrive to the answer

Comment: No idea; if Laravel/Doctrine won't do it you can just use raw SQL query in your migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$table->enum('tableStatus',['Vacant', 'Reserved', 'Occupied', 'For Cleaning']);
```

### First one will be default

Answer (score 4):

You  can  simply  do:

```
$table -> enum('tableStatus',['VACANT','OCCUPIED','RESERVED','FOR CLEANING'])->default('VACANT');
```

Comment: This won't create real ENUM type. It will just add CHECK constraint like this: alter table "ads" add column "status" varchar(255) check ("status" in ('draft', 'in_moderation', 'published', 'declined', 'blocked', 'expired', 'closed', 'sold', 'paused')). And this is totally not you usually want from real PosgreSQL ENUM type which is stored as int value, not varchar and has performance of int type instead of varchar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is explanation: https://hbgl.dev/add-columns-with-custom-types-in-laravel-migrations/

Hope this will save some time for those who meets this problem like me.

In short:

```
Grammar::macro('typeTableTypeEnum', function () {
    return 'tableTypeEnum';
});
 
DB::unprepared("CREATE TYPE tableTypeEnum AS ENUM ('4x4','16x4','8x4');");
 
Schema::create('restaurant_tables', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->addColumn('tableType', 'tableTypeEnum');
    ...
});
```

Alternative version (use for existing table updates):

```
DB::unprepared("CREATE TYPE \"tableTypeEnum\" AS ENUM ('4x4','16x4','8x4');");
DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE "restaurant_tables" add column "tableType" "tableTypeEnum" NOT NULL');
```

Additional steps to extend Doctrine DBAL (required for renaming, for example):

1. Create class `TableTypeEnumDbType`:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Models\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType;

class TableTypeEnumDbType extends StringType
{
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'tableTypeEnum';
    }
}
```

2. add this to `config/database.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Doctrine DBAL settings.
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
'dbal' => [
    'types' => [
        'tableTypeEnum' => \App\Models\Types\AdStatusType::class,
    ],
],
```